# Integrate Qt into existing VS project to replace WinAPI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, user-interface, winapi

I'm using VS2019 and Qt 5.12.9, and I have an old C++ project that currently uses WinAPI for its UI elements. I would like to gradually replace this with UI implemented in Qt, at first targeting specific windows, and eventually phasing out WinAPI altogether. To this end, I have two questions:

1. How do I modify the VS project files so the project will perform all the necessary build operations (.moc files, etc.)?
2. Is it possible to have Qt and WinAPI UI "side-by-side"? In other words, the main window would still use the Windows message loop and window procedures, but for specific windows, I would instantiate Qt objects.

Please keep in mind that the setup described in 2) is a *temporary* solution. I don't intend to juggle the two forever, the project is just too large to completely replace the UI right away.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to start over with a new project and gradually move the existing files into the new project. If you are not using source control like `git` I highly recommend you start now.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I do use source control. Suppose I make a new project and copy over all the old files. Can I still create WinAPI windows, message loop, etc?

Comment: I don't think I would do this all in one step however it probably depends on the code. You are not going to have a WinMain() in a Qt application but I am pretty sure you can create winapi windows from int main() and still have your QMainWidget .. You probably want to test a small test application first.

Comment: You cannot (easily, or reliably) mix Qt and a native Windows message loop. Qt wants to be the One To Rule Them All (and miserably fails in doing so). You *can* still create native windows, but Qt will frequently trash window messages. Silently. If you want to modernize your UI, consider [WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/). It's native, hardware accelerated, supported by Microsoft, and handles keyboard navigation no worse than Qt.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the reply. Part of the reason I want to use Qt is because of Qt Designer, which would make creating and modifying UI elements much less of a pain, especially since it cooperates well with VS. The other nice feature is signals and slots, since I'll have to manage quite a few async operations, but it's not as vital. Does WinUI have anything similar to help with UI design?

Comment: WinUI uses XAML as its markup. Visual Studio comes with a [XAML Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio). The equivalent to signals and slots are *"events"* and *"delegates"*. WinUI is based on the Windows Runtime. As such it gets all the async interfaces. And allows for seamless interop between components written in C++, C#, JavaScript, or Rust, in case that is on your list as well.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I'll give it a try. If it looks like it will work, I'll let you know.

Comment: Forgot to mention the main point: You can migrate to WinUI **at your own pace**. You don't have to change anything in your application. Just start adding WinUI content, or gradually replace existing UI code. That's still a bit tedious with WinUI 2, but WinUI 3 just released its [first preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/).

Comment: Thanks again. Adding an extra comment just to clear everything up, after which I will most likely compile a response with all the recommendations and mark the topic as solved. Does WinUI provide modern C++ wrapper classes for designing UI elements, akin to how Qt lets me subclass dialogs/widgets/etc? I tried looking at the documentation, but there doesn't appear to be an obvious answer.

Comment: That would be [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt). Modern, as in *"requires C++17"*.

Comment: I agree with @IInspectable. WinUI is the modern way to go. If you are familiar with C++17 and XAML you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

So based on the recommendations of @IInspectable in the comments, I decided to try upgrading the app using WinUI instead of Qt. The issues I ran into there will require their own separate question, so for now, I'll post my own conclusions here:

1. If you want to use Qt, the most reliable option is to start an entirely new VS project (and maybe port over some of your backend code). Mixing Qt with WinAPI is just too complicated and unreliable.
2. If you want to use WinUI, keep in mind that *your application will only run on Windows 10*. If that isn't a concern, but you are working with legacy code, you may also need to untangle a lot of old configurations (Windows version defines, etc.) that are necessary for WinUI to work.